# Passing data between components with subject behaviour doesn't work through routing

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have two components both are routed

1.Login and Home component

I pass data from login to home with the help of subject behaviour . The data I send from login page to home page is not successfull. Please have a look at my [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-fpafvs?file=app/views/login/login.component.ts) on stackblitz

```
Here is components
// Login component

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { MessageService } from './../../message.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  template: `
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <button (click)="newMessage()">send message to subject behaviour</button>
  `,
})
export class LoginViewComponent {
  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {}
  newMessage() {
    this.messageService.nextMessage({'style_number': 21,
    'product_id': 23, 'vendor_id': 44});
  }
}

// Home component
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { MessageService } from './../../message.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <h3>Total users: # {{users?.length}}</h3>
    </div>
    <button (click)="newMessage()">send message to subject behaviour</button>
  `,
})
export class HomeViewComponent {

  users;

  constructor(private http: Http, private messageService: MessageService) {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(res => this.users = res)
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.messageService.currentMessage.subscribe(message => {
      console.log('message received', message);
    });
  }
  newMessage() {
    this.messageService.nextMessage({'style_number': 21,
    'product_id': 23, 'vendor_id': 44});
  }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

If someone clicks the button from the login page, I need to see the data immedietly in the home page

Comment: The relevant code must be **in the question itself**.

Comment: the Home component is not instantiated so there's no subscription

Comment: It works fine: send a message from login, then got to the home page, and you'll see the message being logged. What do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: I think he was trying to get data without visiting the home page

Comment: Learn how to `.unsubscribe()` on each subscription, otherwise you get duplication

Comment: @JB Nizet I want to get data immedietly , without visiting the home page.

Comment: Then log it from the service. The home component doesn't exist when you're in the login page. It only exists when you're on the home page.

Comment: What do you mean by log it from service?

Comment: @ JB Please see my edited question with screenshot

Comment: Well, all you're doing in the home component with the received message is `console.log('message received', message);`. You want to do that every time a message is emitted from the service. So move that line of code to the service, inside the `nextMessage()` method.

Comment: Got it. But i need to call a function in the home component.

Comment: You can't: there is no home component when you're in the login page. If you want help, explain what you really want to achieve.

Comment: when user1 sends a message to  user2, The user2 should see the message instantly. So i want to call the http  get service when i receive the message from user1.

Comment: @ JB Nizet Is there a way i can achieve what i need?